# Java compiler error: raw type with method returning Optional

Tags: javac

I'm trying to understand the Java compiler's thinking (I know, bad idea)...

Consider this program:

```
import java.util.Optional;
public class xx {

    public static class Foo<T> {
        public interface Bar<T> {
            int getX();
        }
        public Optional<Bar<T>> getBar() {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Foo();             // note raw type
        foo.getBar().get().getX();
    }
}
```

The java 1.8.0_112 compiler gives:

```
xx.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        foo.getBar().get().getX();
                          ^
  symbol:   method getX()
  location: class Object
1 error
```

The question is: why doesn't the compiler, given the raw type `Foo` for `foo`, realize that the return type of `foo.getBar()` is `Optional<? extends Bar>` instead of what it apparently thinks, which is `Optional<?>` ?

Note: I know how to change this program to make it compile, that's not the question.

Comment: [Type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html)?

Comment: Type erasure is a runtime issue, not a compile time issue. But I know what you mean - it clearly has something to do with the use of a raw type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you use raw types in conjunction with type inference, the following from JLS 18.5.2 will apply

> If unchecked conversion was necessary for the method to be applicable during constraint set reduction in §18.5.1, then [...] the return type and thrown types of the invocation type of m are given by the erasure of the return type and thrown types of m's type.

From this follows, that the return type of `foo.getBar()` is indeed just `Optional` with all type arguments erased.

Solution: avoid raw types, always.